# Does "chmod u+w" mean give the user (owner) writing permissions ("2XY" in octal)?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I understand that `chmod u+w` means give the user/owner (`u`), writing permissions (`w`, which is equivalent to the number `2`), so the new permissions of the file after running the `chmod` command above would be (in octal):

```
2XY
```

Where `2` (equivalent to `write`) is the new owner's permission, and `XY` marks the group/other permissions that weren't modified.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that the only command that actually sets the permissions to 200 is `chmod 200` or `chmod u=w,g-rwx,o-rwx`, which is too dissimilar from the simpler `chmod u+w` that you mentioned in the question to effectively illustrate what the `+` does, which I _believe_ was the point of the question.

Comment: I understand now `chmod u=w,g-rwx,o-rwx` says "set u to 2, and decrease rwx from both g and o".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it actually **adds** the 2 to the original permission the owner had.

So if originally he had only permissions to `read` (4) and `execute` (1), after running `chmod u+w` the owner's permission would be: 1+2+4=7 instead of 5.

If he had only `read` permissions, after the `chmod` command, the owner will have 4+2=6 instead of just 4.

By the way, if the command was `chmod u=w` (**equal** sign instead of a **plus** sign), then you would be correct, and the owner's permission would change to 2 (only `write`). That's the difference between `+` and `=` in the chmod command. The first one **adds** to the permissions, the second one **replaces** them.

That said, if you want to affect all groups (u,g,o) just do, say, `chmod 200`.